# Asyncio subprocess.wait() hangs indefinitely

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

I'm using code derived from [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#subprocess-using-streams). But at sometimes `yield from proc.wait()` just hangs indefinitely and not yield anything. It sometimes hangs and sometimes works. I don't know what the problem really is!

It do generate output or error, but just hangs on the wait()

```
import asyncio.subprocess
import sys

@asyncio.coroutine
def execute():
    code = 'uname -nmprs'

    # Create the subprocess, redirect the standard output into a pipe
    create = asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(code,
                                            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    proc = yield from create

    # Read one line of output
    data = yield from proc.stdout.readline()
    line = data.decode('ascii').rstrip()

    # Wait for the subprocess exit
    yield from proc.wait()
    return line

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
out = loop.run_until_complete(execute())
print("output: %s" % out)
loop.close()
```

Comment: Does the subprocess exit?

Comment: Your example works for me. The problem you describe might happen if the event loop is not set (i.e. without `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)`). Is this what you meant?

Comment: @syntonym no it does not. only hangs at proc.wait()

Comment: @Vincent It works for me. But sometimes it just hangs. It has some unpredictability to it.